# How To handle Multiple Database version in Room DB

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

**How to handle multiple Database version migration in Room DB**
I am unable to manage multiple versions of Database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each Migration has a start and end versions and Room runs these migrations to bring the
   database to the latest version.

---

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_8_9 = new Migration(8, 9) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE  `tableName` ADD COLUMN columeName INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL");
        }
    };
```

---

2.**A migration can handle more than 1 version 
(e.g. if you have a faster path to choose when
going version 3 to 5 without going to version 4). 
If Room opens a database at version
3 and latest version is >= 5,
Room will use the migration object that can migrate from
3 to 5 instead of 3 to 4 and 4 to 5.**